# Facebook Connect

Tags: facebook

I get two errors when I integrate FB with my site:

1. > API Error Code: 191
   >
   > API Error Description: The
   >   specified URL is not owned by the
   >   application
   >
   > Error Message: redirect_uri is not
   >   owned by the application.
2. In the address bar in the FB popup.. `the api key and app id values are the same.`

These errors don't ever happen together - it is either 1 or 2 never both.

Comment: which word don't u understand?

Comment: wats **wrong** in my app

Comment: we don't know your app... mybe some code?

Comment: think no.. atleast i must be able to login... even though i may not be able 2 access their data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what are you trying to do and in which language ?

the second error can be fixed by editing the site_url with the proper on which matches your website url  in website tab in the developer dashboard of your application .

Comment: I am trying to integrate fb and my site.. It was earlier working fine.. I am doing it in **PHP**.. I am able to access my site from inside facebook...So the url may not be incorrect... Also facebook is no longer asking for a callback url...

Answer (score 1):

The redirect URL isn't on the same host that you provided when you registered your application. It has to be the same host - hostname.domainname.com. Any path or file under that is fine, but the host must match your app's settings on Facebook.

Answer (score 0):

You probably didn't set the Site URL in your facebook application settings (edit your app->Website->Site URL) to the URL of your site.

Comment: I did.. when i go to the developer page, i am able to view my site